# Can I send data to Salesforce Analytics / Einstein as JSON and not CSV?

Tags: rest-api, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein, analytics-api

The Salesforce Analytics / Einstein API documentation says that in order to upload actual data to the datasets you need to prepare CSV files and JSON is used only for metadata.
Is there any way to send/upload actual dataset data in Analytics via an API in a JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that but you may explore more  about it doing R and D 
But When you upload the csv file then the datasets itself create a json of it .